# Retrieving data from a collection in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve data that I have stored in the collection in VBA. I am not very sure how to retrieve the data. It gives me a type mismatch error.

My code looks like this:

```
Set col = New Collection
col.Add BGN_arr, "BGN"
col.Add CBBT_arr, "CBBT"

Dim curr_arr() As Variant
Set curr_arr = col("BGN")
```

Tried this as well:

```
Set curr_arr = col.Item ("BGN")
```

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: `curr_arr` is currently a Variant array. Try making it a Variant (i.e., `Dim curr_arr As Variant` without the parenthesis). If that works, I'll explain why.

Comment: Assuming BGN_arr is another array simply remove `set` - you are not dealing with object references

Comment: VBA collections are essentially stunted dictionaries. While there may be some valid use cases for them, the way that you seem to want to use them is fairly dictionary-like. Unless you have a strong reason to avoid them I suggest adding a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime to your project and use dictionaries instead. Dictionary objects have useful methods which have no counterpart in Collection objects (e.g. something as simple as checking if a key exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues I see:

1. You have set `curr_arr() As Variant` - This should not be an array.
2. You are using the `Set` method which will cause an issue.

This code should work:

```
Set col = New Collection
col.Add BGN_arr, "BGN"
col.Add CBBT_arr, "CBBT"

Dim curr_arr As Variant
curr_arr = col.Item ("BGN")
```